# Filtering a list based on a value

Tags: c#

Based on dropdown value and search text I need to filter a list and return.

**Method 1**

```
if (selectedValue == 1 && searchTerm.Length == 0)
return users;

if (selectedValue == 1 && searchTerm.Length > 0)
return users.Where(user=>user.Name == searchTerm).ToList();

if (selectedValue == 2 && searchTerm.Length > 0)
return users.Where(user=>(user.Name == searchTerm && user.Street == "StreetA")).ToList();

if (selectedValue == 2 && searchTerm.Length == 0)
return users.Where(user=>user.Street == "StreetA").ToList();

if (selectedValue == 3 && searchTerm.Length > 0)
return users.Where(user=>(user.Name == searchTerm && user.Street == "StreetB")).ToList();

if (selectedValue == 3 && searchTerm.Length == 0)
return users.Where(user=>user.Street == "StreetB").ToList();
```

**Method 2**

```
if(searchTerm.Length > 0)
{
    if (selectedValue == 1)
    return users.Where(user=>user.Name == searchTerm).ToList();

    if (selectedValue == 2)
    return users.Where(user=>(user.Name == searchTerm && user.Street == "StreetA")).ToList();

    if (selectedValue == 3)
    return users.Where(user=>(user.Name == searchTerm && user.Street == "StreetB")).ToList();
}
else
{
    if (selectedValue == 1)
    return users;

    if (selectedValue == 2)
    return users.Where(user=>user.Street == "StreetA").ToList();

    if (selectedValue == 3)
    return users.Where(user=>user.Street == "StreetB").ToList();
}
```

I am not convenienced with above logics so please help improve this.

Comment: What are you not convinced of? That any of this methods is not correct? Performance? Maintainability?

Comment: @xpereta the logic looks ugly and I feel something better could be done

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`users.Where(user => cond && cond2)` is equivalent to `users.Where(user => cond).Where(user => cond2)`

So you can do the following:

```
IEnumerable<User> resultStream = users;

if(searchTerm.Length > 0)
    resultStream = resultStream.Where(user.Name == searchTerm);

switch(selectedValue){
    case 1: 
        return resultStream.ToList();
    case 2:
        return resultStream.Where(user=>user.Street == "StreetA").ToList();
    case 3:
        return resultStream.Where(user=>user.Street == "StreetB").ToList();
}
```

Comment: You're doing copy-paste code (with a minor variation) in each case within the switch, which is fragile and makes no guarantee of consistent behaviour.  In such a small function, that doesn't but it will scale badly and be fragile each time a new value (with different corresponding filter) is required.  This is a place where a more functional approach would be better.

Comment: @itsbruce you can add another answer explaining that and giving a solution, multiple review focusing on different things are perfectly fine.

Comment: Firstly, I'm not a C# coder so while I know a bad smell, I don't know the most idiomatic C# solutions.  Secondly, there is a only a trivial amendment needed to your code... instead of a switch, an if...

Comment: Don't copy and paste code.  When you're using **switch** or **if**, the branches should only do the things which are different, not contain pasted copies of the things which are the same.  If I knew anything about idiomatic, functional C#, I'd replace the entire switch block with a single return statement.  As it is, I can point out a misfeature and the right basic approach.

Comment: @itsbruce convert that to a proper answer and you will get some upvotes ;)

Comment: I wouldn't deserve them ;)  Comments are often a *good* thing.

Comment: @itsbruce at least pseudocode please :)

Answer (score 4):

You can extract this to a separate method like

```
private bool IsUserValid(User user, string name, string street) 
{
    bool valid = (name.Length == 0) ? true : user.Name == name;
    if (!valid) { return false; }

    valid = (street.Length == 0) ? true : user.Street == street;
    return valid;
}
```

which would then lead to

```
String street = String.Empty;
if (selectedValue == 2) 
{
    street = "StreetA";
} 
else if (selectedValue == 3) 
{
    street = "StreetB";
}
return users.Where(user => IsUserValid(user, searchTerm, street)).ToList();
```

---

Your style omiting braces `{}` is not very good. If you choose to not use braces you really should indent the statements following the `if` like

```
if (selectedValue == 1)
    return users;

if (selectedValue == 2)
    return users.Where(user=>user.Street == "StreetA").ToList();
```

but IMHO the much better style would be to use braces which will make your code less error prone.

Comment: Extracting the method won't work if `users` is some `IQueryable`.

Comment: @svick, but it is a `List<>` (OP is calling .ToList() )

Comment: The *output* is a `List<T>`. That doesn't mean that the *input* has to be one too. You can call `ToList()` on any `IEnumerable<T>` and `IQueryable<T>` inherits from that.

Comment: @svick So just returning `users` does fit this restriction too ?

Comment: It could, if the return type was `IEnumerable<T>`. Though it certainly does make it less likely.

Answer (score 2):

Chains of **if else if** are a very fragile pattern for reasons I've [discussed](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223718/specifics-of-switch-and-if-statements/223731#223731) on StackExchange sites [more than once](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223718/specifics-of-switch-and-if-statements/223731#223731).  You effectively have such a chain in your first code - it's just that the use of **return** allows you to omit the **else**.

It's not just the fragility which is a problem.  **if** is a terrible tool for building anything but simple binary control flows.  If the desired control flow is complex, chained and nested **if** blocks do not express it well and make it hard to reason about.  If it is simple, **if** typically makes it look much more complex than it [should](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/83211/filtering-a-list-based-on-conditions/83259#83259) be.

Your first method is very fragile.  Your second one better shows the structure of the application logic  but still has much duplication.

A **switch** statement is an improvement in that it removes the multiple repetitions of the one condition you are testing.  That said, where there are multiple branches, each doing minor variations of the same thing, more copy-paste code is usually the result, which is fragile for all the same reasons of [**if** chains](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223718/specifics-of-switch-and-if-statements/223731#223731).  The more branches you add, the more fragile it becomes.  One typo can break your code in ways which may be hard to debug.

One simple way to clarify your code is a pared-down version of RatchetFreak's answer:

```
IEnumerable<User> resultStream = users;

if(searchTerm.Length > 0)
    resultStream = resultStream.Where(user.Name == searchTerm);

var streets = new Dictionary<int,string>() {
    {2, "StreetA"}
    {3, "StreetB"}
};
if (streets.ContainsKey(selectedValue))
    resultStream = resultStream.Where(user=>user.Street == streets[selectedValue]);

return resultStream.ToList();
```

Please forgive any compilation errors or choices unsuitable to your version of C#.  I've never written a line of C# in my life (fair amount of Java, for my sins) but tried to find reasonably current, idiomatic options.

Now, important points about this code

- Each important, distinct thing is only done once
- Only one **return** statement
- Use of Dictionary rather than **switch**

Can you see how using the dictionary both simplifies your code and makes it easily extensible?  If you add another drop down option which *does* offer another choice of street, all you have to do is add a new entry in the dictionary; the rest of the code doesn't have to change at all.  If you add another option which is nothing to do with streets, again the street-filtering code is bomb-proof, because it only cares about **selectedValue** if it matches a key in the dictionary.

That said, there are still potential problems inherited from your original code which should be considered.

**Multiple Iterations**

Unless the **resultStream** object is a lazy stream where only the **toList** function forces a full evaluation (I don't know nearly enough about C# to say), the collection is being iterated over twice, which is inefficient.  If it isn't lazy, then it would be more *efficient* to create a filter which combined *all* the constraints and apply it once.  That might make more complex code - might not.

**Direct coupling with input form structure**

This code depends on the precise ordering of your drop down.  If you change the order, the code breaks until you edit the values properly.  That should be abstracted away (the dictionary is only one step in that).

Also worried about **searchTerm**.  Your code should be asking for a valid username, if there is one.  **searchTerm** implies multiple purposes or even the possibility that more terms will be added later.  Abstraction and the use of meaningful names protects your old code from your later additions.

Your code *could* be represented like this:

```
users.FilterByName(searchTerm).FilterByStreet(selectedValue).ToList()
```

where **FilterByName** and **FilterByStreet** are methods which encapsulate the logic.

It could also look like this:

```
users.FilterFromDropDown(searchTerm, selectedValue).ToList()
```

where **FilterFromDropDown** would encapsulate all the filtering logic and you could be sure to iterate only once over the list.  There are various way to do either approach, both Functional and OO.  If you look at the [Java](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/209822/are-too-many-if-else-statements-for-validation-bad/209830#209830) and [Groovy](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/83211/filtering-a-list-based-on-conditions/83259#83259) answers I linked to, maybe that will help.  I think the Groovy one is more useful to you because

1. The question is about filtering, like yours
2. The Groovy idiom maps better onto C#
3. My Groovy answer doesn't encapsulate the control flow, it just greatly simplifies it.