# Nested if statements dependant on nulls

Tags: c#

As far as readability and best practises go I am not sure how best to write this helper method:

Here are two options I have tried:

```
private decimal? selectTolerance(decimal? globalTolerance, decimal? localTolerance)
{
     if(localTolerance == null)
     {
               if(globalTolerance == null){
                   return null;
               }else{
                   return globalTolerance;
               }
     }
    else
     {
               if(globalTolerance == null){
                    return localTolerance;
               }else{
                   if(globalTolerance < localTolerance){
                       return globalTolerance;
                   }else{
                       return localTolerance;
                   }
               }
         }
 }
```

Alternatively,

```
private decimal? selectTolerance(decimal? globalTolerance, decimal? localTolerance)
{
           if (localTolerance == null && globalTolerance == null)
           {
               return null;
           }

           if (localTolerance != null && globalTolerance == null)
           {
               return localTolerance;
           }

           if (localTolerance == null && globalTolerance != null)
           {
               return globalTolerance;
           }

           if (globalTolerance < localTolerance)
           {
               return globalTolerance;
           }
           else
           {
               return localTolerance;
           }
  }
```

Which of these are better? Any other alternatives?

Comment: Neither is good.   Both have way too many ifs and elses.  Answer on its way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Methods should always be named in `PascalCase`.

You can condense the logic to the following:

```
private decimal? SelectTolerance(decimal? globalTolerance, decimal? localTolerance)
{
    if (localTolerance == null || globalTolerance == null)
    {
        return localTolerance ?? globalTolerance;
    }
    return Math.Min(globalTolerance.Value, localTolerance.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The first step you can take to hugely simplify this function is to start it like this:

```
    if (globalTolerance == null)
        return localTolerance;
```

Why does that work?  Because if both parameters are **null**, you want to return **null** - and the above line will do that.  If **globalTolerance** is **null** but **localTolerance** is not **null**, you want to return the value of **localTolerance** - and the above line does that too.  And is way simpler.

Then all you need is

```
    if (localTolerance == null)
        return globalTolerance;

    return (globalTolerance < localTolerance) ? globalTolerance : localTolerance;
```

The ternary operator offers a simple way to return whichever is lower.  So the full code is

```
private decimal? SelectTolerance(decimal? globalTolerance, decimal? localTolerance)
{
    if (globalTolerance == null)
        return localTolerance;

    if (localTolerance == null)
        return globalTolerance;

    return (globalTolerance < localTolerance) ? globalTolerance : localTolerance;
}
```

Simples.

Chains of **if** (and, even worse, **if... else... if**) are very fragile for reasons I've [explained](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223718/specifics-of-switch-and-if-statements/223731#223731) [quite](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/83907/filtering-a-list-based-on-a-value/83995#83995) [often](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/209822/are-too-many-if-else-statements-for-validation-bad/209830#209830) on various [StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/83211/filtering-a-list-based-on-conditions/83259#83259) sites.  Rather than rehearse all the reasons again here, take a look at my other answers for both an explanation of the faults of that kind of a control structure and a range of ways to avoid it.

Comment: Your code returns `null` when `globalTolerance != null` and `localTolerance == null`. It should return `globalTolerance`.

Comment: Oops.  Very good point.  Was in too much of a hurry - my bad.  Fixed.